Application of Roche's theorem
Let $a>1$ be real number. Prove that $z\exp(a-z)=1$ has a single solution in $\mathbb{D}_1(0)$, which is real and positive.
approach:
Take $f(z)=z\exp(a-z)-1$ and $g(z)= z\exp(a-z)$ then
$$|z\exp(a-z)-1-\exp(a-z)|=1<|z\exp(a-z)|=\exp(a-Re(z))$$
on boundary of the disc. Now this tells me that $z\exp(a-z)-1$ has same amount of zeroes with $z\exp(a-z)$. Hence it must have 1 zero.
As for the part where it says real and positive, I do not know how to conclude. Is this correct and any hint for the real and positive part would be appreciated!

It is enough to check that $ze^{a-z}$ takes the value $1$ in the real interval $(0,1)$. At $0$ the function vanishes and at $1$ it takes eh value $e^{a-1} >1$. By Intermediate Value property we see that there is a solution in $(0,1)$.
